# Why can my vpshost server see my vpses but my other machines can't?

Tags: webserver, vps

I've just installed ubuntu server 12.04 to a new machine, on that server I have two VPS, each of them are running ubuntu server 12.04 as well.

I cannot seem to find my vps from any other machine on the network other than the vpshost machine where they are running.
Pinging vps1 from vpshost:
        64 bytes from 192.168.122.94: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms

Pinging vps1 from my laptop via winxp:
    Pinging 192.168.122.94 with 32 bytes of data:

```
Request timed out.
```

I get a similar error when I try to browse to the server via firefox (they're both running apache). 
    The connection has timed out
    The server at 192.168.122.139 is taking too long to respond.

As part of a tutorial I did create a bridge, could it be possible the bridge is not working, and thus not allowed anything external to see them?

What the bridge looks like:
    auto br0
    iface br0 inet static
            address 192.168.1.43
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            network 192.168.1.0
            broadcast 192.168.1.255
            gateway 192.168.1.1
            bridge_ports eth0
            bridge_fd 9
            bridge_hello 2
            bridge_maxage 12
            bridge_stp off